# cannot edit \sectionmark with titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I want to have unumbered chapters/sections appearing in the headers, so I used titlesec and defined a pagestyle that only displays the chapter/section title in the left/right marks. Now, I want that numbered chapters show as "Chapter X. Chapter title", for sections it would be "X.Y Section title". For unumbered it would be just "Chapter title" and "Section title".

My solution is to edit the `\chaptermark` and the `\sectionmark` like this :

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\chaptermark{This is a test \thechapter. #1}\bfseries \Huge}
{\chaptertitlename \hspace{0ex} \thechapter}
{2ex}
{#1}
```

It works for chapters, unumbered chapters, unumbered sections **but not for sections**

MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{myps}[\scshape]{%
  \sethead[\footnotesize \oldstylenums{\thepage}][][\chaptertitle]% even
          {\sectiontitle}{}{\footnotesize \oldstylenums{\thepage}} % odd
}

\titleformat{name=\chapter , numberless}
 {\chaptermark{#1}\normalfont\bfseries\Huge \filcenter}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {#1}
 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\chaptermark{This is a test \thechapter. #1}\bfseries \Huge}
{\chaptertitlename \hspace{0ex} \thechapter}
{2ex}
{#1}

\titleformat{\section}
{\sectionmark{This is a test \thesection #1} \Large \bfseries \filcenter}
{\thesection}
{0.7em}
{#1}

\titleformat{name=\section , numberless}
{\sectionmark{#1} \Large \bfseries \filcenter}
{}
{0.7em}
{#1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myps}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}
test
\newpage
test
\newpage
test
\end{document}
```

`\chapter` should display this
[image]

`\chapter*`should display this
[image]

`\section` should display this
[image]

`\section*` should display this
[image]

**The issue :**

`\section` displays this
[image]

because the following code is not functionnal

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\sectionmark{This is a test \thesection #1} \Large \bfseries \filcenter}
{\thesection}
{0.7em}
{#1}
```

meanwhile all the others are functionnal.

Comment: titlesec sets marks too, and in the case of sectioning commands it actually sets two: one before and one after your manual \sectionmark and so your value is lost.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is strange, do you know why it does this only with section and not chapter and others ?

Comment: chapters have a \newpage before, that makes their code easier.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but then why does it work with `\section*` ?

Comment: it doesn't issue an internal \sectionmark, so yours win.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So what would be the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really say how you call numberless chapters/sections. If you change the `secnumdepth` counter you can use the tools of titlesec. If you want it also for starred chapters and section you are out of luck: titlesec doesn't set the marks and there is no interface to reinsert them and patching titlesec is not trivial (even hyperref doesn't do it ...). You best bet is then to define new commands which issue the mark commands:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{myps}[\scshape]{%
  \sethead[\footnotesize \oldstylenums{\thepage}][][\ifthechapter{Chapter~\thechapter~}{}\chaptertitle]% even
          {\ifthesection{Section~\thesection~}{}\sectiontitle}{}{\footnotesize \oldstylenums{\thepage}} % odd
}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{name=\chapter , numberless}
 {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\filcenter}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {#1}
 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries \Huge}
{\chaptertitlename \hspace{0ex} \thechapter}
{2ex}
{#1}

\titleformat{\section}
{\Large \bfseries \filcenter}
{\thesection}
{0.7em}
{#1}

\titleformat{name=\section , numberless}
{\Large \bfseries\filcenter}
{}
{0.7em}
{#1}

\newcommand\starredchapter[1]{%
 \chapter*{#1}\chaptermark{#1}}

\newcommand\starredsection[1]{%
 \section*{#1\sectionmark{#1}}\sectionmark{#1}}
 
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}

test
\newpage
test
\newpage
test

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\chapter{Nonumber Chapter title}
\section{Nonumber Section title}
test
\newpage
test
\newpage
test

\starredchapter{Starred Chapter title}
\starredsection{Starred Section title}

test
\newpage
test
\newpage
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited to clarify how I want to call numberless chapters/sections

Comment: well as I wrote: it is difficult to get this to work with the starred versions, it would require internal patches.  Use another command as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps define a custom section command for numbered sections, which defines a `\sectionmark` just after the section:

```
\newcommand{\numberedsection}[1]{\section{#1}\sectionmark{This is a test \thesection\ #1}}
```

And change the style for the numbered section so:

```
\titleformat{\section}
{ \Large \bfseries \filcenter}
{\thesection}
{0.7em}
{#1}
```

For unnumbered sections, you use `\section*` normally.